# Check the status of last SQL statement that was executed in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

How to check the status of the last SQL statement that was executed in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Code:

```
SET @SQLStmt = N'CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCSI ON '+ @DBName +N'.dbo.' + @ResultTableName + N' WITH ( DROP_EXISTING = OFF )'

EXEC dbo.pCOMMON_PrintVariable ': Create Clustered Columnstore Index: ', @SQLStmt
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt
```

Would like to check the status of the above statement and trigger some code after these statements.

Comment: What do you mean by status?

Comment: Status - Executed successfully or Failed?

Comment: When I start seeing DDL in a stored procedure I am concerned that there are some serious architecture problems. And even more so when you want to ignore errors. This is a solid indication that something is very far off here.

Answer (score 1):

Append the below code after the statement for which status needs to be checked:

```
IF(@@ERROR <> 0)
    BEGIN
      // error occurred - place error-handling tasks here
      SELECT 'ERROR'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      // code executed successfully
      SELECT 'SUCCESS'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the statement you want to check in a [TRY..CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql) block.  If it fails, it will go to the CATCH block.   If it succeeds, it will go to the next statement after it.

Sample psuedo code:

```
BEGIN TRY
  SET @SQLStmt = N'CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCSI ON '+ @DBName +N'.dbo.' + @ResultTableName + N' WITH ( DROP_EXISTING = OFF )'

  EXEC dbo.pCOMMON_PrintVariable ': Create Clustered Columnstore Index: ', @SQLStmt
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStmt  

  --do whatever you want to do if the above statements succeed
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  --do whatever you want to do if the above statements fail
END CATCH
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code that is workable.. Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to do anything if the statement fails. Thing is I want to insert data into a table only when the above exec statement I posted becomes successful otherwise I would like to skip it.

Comment: Then just don't put anything in the CATCH block.

Comment: So what happens by using BEGIN TRY END TRY ? Would it ignore all the failed statements and accept only the successful statements.

Comment: Recommend you read the linked documentation.   It's too much to explain here, but basically as soon as an error is encountered in a TRY block, the code skips to the CATCH block, and all subsequent commands in the TRY block are ignored.